# Как узнать разделяется ли число на 3 без модуля на JavaScript или на Java?

Tags: javascript, java

Как узнать разделяется ли число на 3 без модуля на JavaScript или на Java ?

Такой вариант не подходит

```js
age % 3 == 0
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Почему не подходит?
Озвучьте задачу полностью

Comment: Такое задание у меня, решить данную задачу без использование модуля

Comment: Ну воспользуйтесь школьным признаком делимости на три по сумме цифр

Comment: Ещё в JS (про Java не знаю) можно перевести число в троичную систему и проверить что последняя цифра 0

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Разделить два раза, второй раз округлить, отбросив все что после запятой, и отнять от первого результата, получаем остаток и понимаем, делится ли число на цело или нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего в твоём задание требуется использовать свойство, что, если сумма цифр в числе делится на 3 без остатка, то и само число делится на 3.

К примеру

```
2145
2+1+4+5=12
1+2=3

2145/3=715 (без остатка)
```

```
3457
3+4+5+7=19 
1+9=10
1+0=1

3457/3=1152,(3) (т.е. 1152 и остаток 1)
```

P.S. та же история с деление числа на 9

Answer (score 1):

Я вот этим пользуюсь:

```js
function remDiv(a,b){
  return a/b-~~(a/b);
}
var res=remDiv(8,5);
console.log('Остаток: '+res+', делится на цело: '+(res==0?'да':'нет'));
res=remDiv(8,4);
console.log('Остаток: '+res+', делится на цело: '+(res==0?'да':'нет'));
```